# VBA Beer Tank Status Indicator

Tags: excel, vba

Attempting to build a dashboard of sorts in Excel, that will visually display status of fermentation tanks based on simple log of batches of beer brewed.

[FV1] [FV2] [FV3] [FV4]  <-----These will change color and populate with brewdate and type of beer. These are just uniquely formatted cells now, but could be any button object etc.

```
BREWDATE   BRAND      TANK  XFERDATE
7/1/2015   Bud.Lite   FV2    7/15/15
7/2/2015   Budweiser  FV3
```

XFERDATE represents when beer was pumped out of the tank to go somewhere else in the plant. I'm attempting to have indicator cells display a blank state when empty, then change color after BREWDATE to indicate full, and then empty again after XFERDATE. In above example, FV2 indicator would be in blank state since the value is not blank, while FV3 would have changed to active state on 7/2 when filled with beer.

Any ideas? Seemed to be just simple conditional statement, but I can't seem to figure out sequencing to make it continuously update. Any help appreciated.

C

Comment: I think you need to make a cell where you put the current date. Then you can just do conditional formatting. Every time you change the data in that cell, the formats will update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I made this little setup. You could do the same, just change around the columns. And I just noticed that you don't need to implement the if statement I did in the green rule, you can just do it as it is done in the yellow rule. Yellow in this case shows empty tanks, and green shows full tanks. Tanks that haven't been used I did not colour, that is the first rule. But you can leave that out as well, then they would all turn yellow.

EDIT after your screenshot:

[image]

I first selected the imput data and ordered them descending on brewdate, so always the most recent value is found first when using VLOOKUP.

I used the following formula's: 
In H6 to M6:

```
=IF(H$8="Full",VLOOKUP(H$5,$A$2:$D100,2,FALSE),"")
```

In H7 to M7:

```
=IF(H$8="Full",VLOOKUP(H$5,$A$2:$D101,3,FALSE),"")
```

In H8 to M8

```
=IF(ISBLANK(VLOOKUP(H$5,$A$2:$D102,4,FALSE)),"Full","Empty")
```

And in conditional formatting for H6 to M8

```
=H$8="Empty"   (format fill yellow)
=H$8="Full"    (format fill green)
```

Comment: That's definitely one component of what i wanted to accomplish, but the table will be continuously update with new beers being pumped into the same tanks, and my objective was to have static indicators displaying the current status of each tank. This image is what I thought it would look like, I just updated manually, rather than with formula or code. Hope this is more clear, thanks!              http://imgur.com/xzlLoOg

Comment: Ah I see. Then VBA would come in most helpful, although it should also be possible with common excel codes. I'll think about it some more during the day.

Comment: I updated my answer. I believe this is what you are looking for.

Comment: nailed it, that was perfect. I used a couple helper columns and a modification to VLOOKUP to search from the bottom, since I enter data chronologically, with each new row as a different batch. YOU ROCK, thanks! Will buy you a beer if you're ever in the states.                                                                                                                                                     PS - Here is mod to VLOOKUP for future searchers looking for method http://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/602251-vlookup-search-from-bottom-to-top.html